# Boolean Algebra simplification help

Tags: boolean-algebra

A'B'CD' + A'BCD + AB'C'D + AB'CD + ABC'D'

I have tried using a k map and I got it down to AC'D' + A'B'CD' + A'BCD + AB'CD.
Also I think AB'C'D + AB'CD can be simplified to ABD'

Trying to simplify this. Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: The people on this site love mathematics, and we like to help others learn it. But we hate it when people try to use us to avoid learning it themselves (which happens a lot). So please show us that you are attempting to learn it for yourself by telling us what you've attempted and what has you stumped. that will allow us to provide exactly what you need.

Comment: @peterlany1975 yes, the 3rd and 4th terms simplify (but you have a wrong result, there should be AB'D), the rest cannot be simplified... unless you'd be satisfied with any form.

Comment: @user376343 Thank you for the heads up and I'd be satisfied with any form if you could help that would be great.